# PHP - get all json data from url and save it to sql

Tags: php, json

With this code i get a single curreny and can save it to a sql db

```
$url = "https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummary?market=BTC-NEO";
$response = file_get_contents($url);
$obj = json_decode($response,true);

$marketname = $obj['result'][0]['MarketName'] . '';
$high= $obj['result'][0]['High'] . '';

$sql = "INSERT INTO markets (market,high) VALUES ('$marketname','$high')";
...
```

With this URL i can get ALL currencies

```
$url = "https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummaries";
```

Now the question.. I want to save ALL Currencies in the Database. So how i get all data to my string and save all to DB? This is not the correct way..

```
$url = "https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummaries";
$response = file_get_contents($url);
$obj = json_decode($response,true);

$marketname = $obj['result']['MarketName'] . '';
...
```

Any idea?

Comment: What have you tried? What is your specific problem? Or do you simpy want us to do your work for you?

Comment: `Any idea?` yes, several. If you can pay me a reasonable fee I can turn these ideas into reality.....

Comment: Do you know `for()` or `foreach()`...?

Comment: i think $marketname = $obj['result'][0] ...  [1] .... [2] etc.. is not the best idea, because i dont know how many entries. maybe the solution is to check how many entries (currencies) are there and then save 0-250 (eg.) into an array !? i don't know.. i tried it a few hours, but i think i'm on the wrong thinking way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just looping your result and insert every item to database, like this

```
...

foreach($obj['result'] as $result) {
    $marketname = $result['MarketName'];
    $high = $result['High'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO markets (market,high) VALUES ('$marketname','$high')";

    ...
}

...
```

Comment: damn.. thank you! the solution is so close.. I have to sleep more to concentrate! you really helped me a lot